# Creating a From - To Component in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I was writing a simple GUI where I need a lot of From-To fields for example:

1. Weight From To
2. Height From To
3. etc.

At the moment I'm laying out three components for each such input:

1. A Label
2. A From TextBox
3. A To TextBox

This becomes very tedious very quickly.

I was thinking of Developing a From - To components -- is this the right way to go. Any references on how to best do this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd say, yes, your ideas are sound, and sowhy not give it a go as you've nothing to lose in the trying.

Comment: Well I figured I was trying to solve a common problem and before I did it -- there would be a library of such components or some standard advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by create a new base class which extends from `JPanel`.

Within this class, declare the from and to fields.  Setup the layout, create and add your components to.

Provide setter and getter methods to allow you to adjust the values of the fields, for example...

```
public void setToValue(String text) {
    toField.setText(text);
}

public String gtToValue() {
    return toField.getText();
}
```

You may also want to provide a setter to allow you to change the label as well.

When needed, create an instance of this component and it to your UI and populate it with the values you need

You could extend this idea to also provide a validation model of some kind to allow you to validate the to and from fields when they change, but lets keep to basics.

Take a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

Comment: that's what I was thinking of doing -- my question really was has no one already done this -- this must be a very standard problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you're look for a component library, then we can't help, as that is primary opinionated, besides, everybody will have their own requirements. For example, I've developed an abstract concept of what you're talking about which allow implementations to define the type of value and editors for the component, which has allowed us to design date ranges, number ranges, combo ranges...and just about any other range you can think of, but that's our requirement (and no, I can't give you the code, it's company code ;))

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a component to supply a range.  There's nothing out-of-the box, so you'll have to roll your own.

If your ranges are numeric in nature, one approach is to customize a `JSlider` so that has 2 thumbs instead of one.  The left thumb would enable the setting of the lower value, and the second thumb to supply the upper value. This is similar to what you would see on car buying websites that ask you for a price range to shop.

Here are some different approaches from the web:

- [Creating a Java Swing range slider](http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/)
- [MultiThumbSlider](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ThumbSliderExample2.htm)
- [JXMultiThumbSlider](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Swing-Library/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXMultiThumbSlider.java.htm) from SwingX